# Test return of arrow function in setState call React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to mock the showAllElements function to see if my setElements state is being set correctly. Here is the react snippet.

```
function functionalComponent(){
 const [elements, setElements] = React.useState([{"isHidden": true}]);
        
        
 function showAllElements() {
  setElements((elements) =>
   elements.map((element) => {
    element.isHidden = false;
    return element;
   })
  );
 }

 return (
  <SideBar
   showAllElements={showAllElements}
  />
}
```

Here is my jest/enzyme snippet. However when I run my test, I'm getting [Anonymous Function], instead of an array of elements with the field isHidden set to false.

```
    it("Should set the field isHidden to false on all elements", async () => {
      Sidebar.invoke("showAllElements")();
      functionalComponent.update();
      expect(setElements).toHaveBeenCalledWith([{"isHidden": false}]);
    });
```

I am mocking setElements using jest.fn()
This approach works for setStates that don't use arrow functions, such as this one.

```
    it("Open Sidebar", async () => {
      SideBar.invoke("setIsSideBarVisible")(true);
      actionMapper.update();
      expect(setIsSideBarVisible).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon further reading two options have come forward, using callbacks in a provider / creating a hook vs using redux.

We chose to proceed with Redux, using a reducer to abstract this logic allowing jest to mock everything without using any anonymous functions.